# Allocating More Space for C Struct to Improve Performance?

Tags: c, optimization, memory-management

I am working on something that required me to create a structure similar to

```
typedef struct vector {
    int dimension;
    double* data;
} Vctr;
```

and I thought that accessing elements of the member, data, might be faster if I could have data stored in the same area as an allocated vector and so I decided to try

```
// replaces vector->data[i]
#define data(name, x) *( ( double* )name + sizeof( int ) + sizeof( double ) )

typedef struct vector {
    int dim;
    double* data;
} Vctr;

Vctr* vMake( double* data, int dim )
{
    assert( dim > 0 );

    // Allocating enough space for vector and the data member
    Vctr* retVal = malloc( sizeof( Vctr ) + (size_t)(dim - 1) * sizeof( double ) );
    retVal->dim = dim;

    // copy data into the vector
    while( dim ) data( retVal, --dim ) = data[dim];

    return retVal;
}
```

I wrote the macro data(name, x) in the hopes that it too might further improve things based on the function vMake.

Does this do anything at all to increase performance in a data processing heavy program?

Comment: This seems like the perfect job for cap'n [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)!

Comment: Shooting elephants with wild pointers is generally a bad idea. (aka undefined behaviour) Use either an array solely or a flexible array member.

Comment: @Kninnug Thanks! The courses that I've been taking that use C have only used C89 so I did not know about that but I will use that instead whenever I need to.

Comment: As a side note: It's quite confusing to use the same name, `data`, for a function, a function argument and a struct field.

Comment: FAM will avoid the pointer dereference and generally cache misses (which can be huge).

Comment: Yeah, after taking a look at flexible array members it does exactly what I want it to.

Comment: First, trying to access objects like `double` only via addresses you compute is a good way to generate a `SIGBUS` signal and/or hurt performance. Many architectures have specific address alignment restrictions, and even for those that don't there can be significant performance differences based on object alignment.  And if you're worried about performance, just crank up the optimization level of your compiler. It's extremely unlikely that you'll be able to write general code faster than what the compiler will generate, and the compiler will know about the alignment restrictions.